# JavaScript updating global variables in different file concurrently without interference

Tags: javascript, node.js

Please how would I go about calling a JavaScript function in Node JS located in a different file and have it update some global variables there, then each time it's called again it won't interfere with the global variables there updated during the previous call?

Basically having as many separate, independent instances of a .js file as needed which were triggered by a function call from main file. The .js files would end after having their job done, so there wouldn't be thousands of files running concurrently forever.

So for example I call function F located in separate file from main file and pass it parameters A,B - that updates some global parameters in the separate file. Then I want to call function F again with different parameters C,D which again updates some global parameters in the separate file, but it DOESN'T change and intervene with the parameters that were updated during the first call.

Hope this makes sense friends.

Thank you very much.

Comment: F must be a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class) (which you can define in a separate file), and each caller must create a fresh instance `var f = new F()` and pass it the parameters (`f.A = ...`). That way, all instances are independent. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You simply use IMPORT and EXPORT. Each time you call imported function, it starts in a new instance not related to any instances that are running currently.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/import-and-export-in-node-js/